# npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/home/vagrant/code/proadco.test/node_modules/.bin/parser'

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm attempting to execute `npm install` in Git Bash client on Windows 8.1 but receiving the following error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@1.2.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/proadco.test/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist/package.json.737544774'

npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/home/vagrant/code/mysite.test/node_modules/.bin/parser'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-06-24T02_39_32_641Z-debug.log
```

Running `npm install --no-bin-links` allows it to run successfully. But I don't full understand the consequences of this action. I believe it's saying "Don't create a symlink. Which is just a hack instead of resolving the root of the issue. But I've read that Windows doesn't support symlinks so it's impossible to solve.

Can someone explain what the consequences here are? And possibly how to overcome the root issue of symlinks?

Comment: symlinks are supported on windows. Are you running as administrator?

Answer (score 32):

What worked for me was to start Windows command prompt as **Administrator** and `vagrant up` from there.

**If Vagrant is already running**, you will need to run `vagrant suspend` before `vagrant up` in your newly administrator-enabled command prompt.

The problem is that **the Vagrant process needs administrator privileges** to create `symlinks`.

To get a rid of a previous unsuccessful installation, I ran `npm clean-install`. `npm run dev` still ends up with some errors but `ui:auth` works.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the tip about 'clean-install', otherwise I was still getting other errors

Comment: This worked for Vagrant as well-  to be crystal clear - I needed to run the windows command prompt as admin and then run vagrant up/ vagrant reload. After which ssh into vagrant and run my npm command.

Comment: Worked for `EPROTO` error when running `npx create-react-app .`.

Comment: This is the perfect answer without any hack. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

In case you want npm to stop from creating symlinks for you, you can avoid that by

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

more information about it on npm documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html

> Note: This might have some unknown side effects, this methods worked
>   fine for an application I was working on and when I encountered this
>   issue. The side effects might be related to symlink, which npm is
>   trying to create, and in the later phase of development it finds out
>   that the symlink is not available.

Comment: Just a small heads-up: This has the potential to break builds. Some packages will not work with this option.

Comment: @JellyFilledNuts yes Sir, had mentioned that with a small note :)

Answer (score 5):

## For Windows Host

[This easy solution](https://medium.com/@dtinth/isolating-node-modules-in-vagrant-9e646067b36) can exclude `node_modules` folder from syncing with vagrant default sync provider (not rsync nor nfs).

Just `vagrant ssh` onto your gest machine and execute these commands:

```sh
$ mkdir ~/project_node_modules
$ sudo mount --bind ~/project_node_modules /home/vagrant/code/project/node_modules
```

## Not for Windows Host

***Warning! You need `rsync` on both host and guest machines!***

I found that is possible to exlude `node_modules` folder from syncing with Windows filesystem in order to **avoid the symlink problem**.

In the Homestead `Vagrantfile` this line will activate Rsync support for the folder you chose, but excluding right the `node_modules` folder:

```rb
config.vm.synced_folder "C:\\path\\to\\project", "/home/vagrant/path/to/project", type: "rsync", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"], rsync__exclude: ['node_modules/']
```

If it sounds difficult, you can follow the Homestead documentation at *[Configuring Shared Folder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#configuring-shared-folders)* putting this in your `Homestead.yaml` file:

```yaml
folders:
    - map: ~/code/project1
      to: /home/vagrant/project1
      type: "rsync"
      options:
          rsync__args: ["--verbose", "--archive", "--delete", "-zz"]
          rsync__exclude: ["node_modules"]
```

Now, running command `npm install` will be able to install all the project dependencies and command `npm run dev` will be able to produce the mix manifest correctly.

Comment: Worked for me, however is unresponsive to `npm run watch`,  any idea how to configue it to run with watch?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by

> i was fighting this case for days, finally i ve installed all the node module dependencies "using IDE" and its fixed

> ulas korpe

My problem was with laravel/homestead and win11 - they seemd to have conflicts and I couldn't get around them via vagrant. But the genious idea of going local, and editing files outside of the VM ( in the shared folder ) is the perfect solution.

So yeah, running

> npm install

locally not on a VM solves this problem for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31422603)

Comment: This absolutely does answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was this. In the Homestead environment I used:

```
sudo su
```

then run again

```
npm install
```

Comment: This question is old, but I just ran into this same issue.  I had a project that had been compiling correctly forever and then just stopped working on my windows machine with vagrant and virtual box.  Running powershell as and administrator had always worked in the past, but out of the blue it would no longer create symlinks.  After hours of trying to solve the issue I found this.  Running sudo su inside the VM restored the necessary privileges for vargrant to create symlinks. @stefan-pavlov, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i was fighting this case for days, finally i ve installed all the node module dependencies "using IDE"   and its fixed